# `sysctl` not available in script started by swanctl on NixOS

Tags: linux, vpn, nixos, sysctl

I use **strongswan-swanctl** on a VPN server running **NixOS**.

Basically it is working and I can connect to the VPN server from clients.

```
  services.strongswan-swanctl = {                                            
    enable = true;                                                           
    swanctl = {                                                              
      authorities = {                                                        
        "vpnca" = {                                                          
          cacert = "ca-cert.pem";                                            
        };                                                                   
      };                                                                     
      connections = {                                                        
        "ikev2-eap" = {                                                      
          version = 2;                                                       
          proposals = [ "aes192gcm16-aes128gcm16-prfsha256-ecp256-ecp521"    
                        "aes192-sha256-modp3072"                             
                        "default" ];                                         
          rekey_time = "0s";                                                 
          pools = [ "primary-pool-ipv4" "primary-pool-ipv6" ];               
          fragmentation = "yes";                                             
          dpd_delay = "30s";                                                 
          local."1" = {                                                      
            certs = [ "vpn_example_com.pem" ];                              
            id = "@vpn.example.com";                                        
          };                                                                 
          remote."1" = {                                                     
            auth = "eap-mschapv2";                                           
            eap_id = "%any";                                                 
          };                                                                 
          children = {                                                       
            "ikev2-eap" = {                                                  
              local_ts = [ "0.0.0.0/0" "::/0" ];                             
              rekey_time = "0s";                                             
              dpd_action = "clear";                                          
              esp_proposals = [ "aes192gcm16-aes128gcm16-prfsha256-ecp256-modp3072"
                                "aes192-sha256-ecp256-modp3072"              
                                "default" ];                                 
              updown = "/etc/swanctl/proxyndp.updown";                       
            };                                                               
          };                                                                 
          local_addrs = [ "192.0.2.1" "2001:db8::2"];         
        };                                                                   
      };
```

The problem I have is inside the `/etc/swanctl/proxyndp.updown` script:

```sh
#! /bin/sh

case $PLUTO_VERB in
     up-client-v6)
         sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
         sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.proxy_ndp=1
         ip -6 neigh add proxy ${PLUTO_PEER_CLIENT%????} dev ens3
     ;;
     down-client-v6)
         ip -6 neigh delete proxy ${PLUTO_PEER_CLIENT%????} dev ens3
     ;;
esac
```

The program `sysctl` isn't found by the system when executing this script. On a normal user shell I see the tool in `/run/current-system/sw/bin/sysctl` but for this script I get the following log messages in the system journal:

```
Feb 12 16:04:01 vpn.example.com charon-systemd[9249]: updown: /etc/swanctl/proxyndp.updown: line 5: sysctl: command not found
Feb 12 16:04:01 vpn.example.com charon-systemd[9249]: updown: /etc/swanctl/proxyndp.updown: line 6: sysctl: command not found
```

**Note:** `ip` is in the same folder and can be run by the script.

Any idea what's going wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Behaviour definition outside Nix expressions

It looks to me like you put the `proxy.updown` file by yourself in `/etc`. That is something you shouldn't do on NixOS, as your system behaviour then wouldn't only depend on your Nix expressions. Everything should be managed in your `configuration.nix` (or files imported by `configuration.nix`). Instead of setting the path in `services.strongswan-swanctl.swanctl.connections."ikev2-eap".children."ikev2-eap".updown`, you can directly supply the content of the file:

```
updown = ''
  sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
  ...
'';
```

#### sysctl: command not found

The `sysctl` binary is not found, because it is not part of the systemd service PATH, as you can see [here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/6336f9e6ea25bcc3f8049d56c660ebed5ac7d943/nixos/modules/services/networking/strongswan-swanctl/module.nix#L67) in the sources. One easy fix for that is to directly reference the Nix store path of `sysctl` in the updown script with `"${pkgs.procps}/bin/sysctl ..."`.

```
updown = ''
  ${pkgs.procps}/bin/sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
  ...
'';
```

On build time, that expression is transformed to something like `"/nix/store/8f9cypv6vw5hwkh49l1j6b1rkxi4dbsq-procps-3.3.15/bin/sysctl ..."`.

#### Alternative to using sysctl command

If you could live with the sysctl option being defined all the time and not just when your interface is up, you could use the `boot.kernel.sysctl` option.

```
{ config, pkgs, lib, ...}:{
  boot.kernel.sysctl = {
    "net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding" = "1";
    "net.ipv6.conf.all.proxy_ndp" = "1";
  };

  services.strongswan-swanctl = {
  ...
}
```

#### Resources

I've never used `strongswan` but I think a valuable resource for learning NixOS best practices are the NixOS tests. The [strongswan](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/6336f9e6ea25bcc3f8049d56c660ebed5ac7d943/nixos/tests/strongswan-swanctl.nix) one defines three virtual machines, boots them and tests, wether the first machine can ping the third one through the VPN.

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful answer. I went with the boot.kernel.sysctl way as I think it's the cleanest. Putting the call to the updown script was more or less a hack as I found no other place to add it. -- I was aware of the tests, but somehow I couldn't transfer it to my problem. In general I'm more the reading books to get the deeper relations style learner, than the copy, paste, adapt style learner.

Comment: Glad I could help!